# Vega Line Chart add tooltip

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

Could anyone help to add a tooltip to my Line Chart example?

I tried to add something like but no luck

```
 tooltip: [
    { field: 'x', type: 'quantitative' },
    { field: 'y', type: 'quantitative' },
    { field: 'c', type: 'quantitative' },
 ],
```

Docs from [vega lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-tooltip/vega-lite-examples.html) does not provide any working example for Line chart.

Install of vega-tooltip does not help as well

My spec at [Vega Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJgpgzgxgTgSwA4BcEHsB2IBcIAq6KAhgDYAEAwugK6YrmkKYTkwAWxcKAdCADQgA7gjAp2uAIwAmAAyzB7CAgDm7FLgAsAVgUgkxMGGYrc2wVFWYyUXAG1Q1gLYRcIZighwk6UsU8CIABuZDSueEwsXCAAvgC6gqQQKhCYYLY4DiAAZgikpG4wvuhwgSUIqRp4AEZEKOhOgcZwEDBoWG7s5QBeWCQFFgCeTrWk+INI4SBQAI40XK7xgmD+xPaOxC5uJNVJgSGkYRlZAB64eoNSOoIwbgCC+bH8oGc4koKXb9oAzDf3jzFniBXtIPrhpAAOPS3PAPAqAl64X4gT6SXR-WEAoGvTRgnCQ6H-eHYsx4ySaQmY4mInAANjxAE5KSA4U8aRckcyAEI0UgAazYXEQXjZwKkeLkGJAPP5grgwtKCLF+MZ3N5ApgQoqipJOGRn1patlmvl2tFOLx6JAMOl6rlCvNpJRWiNGq1IqVr3pzrervtZs950tzPwxEwfK85Cg7GQjreZJDYYjcCjMaQcdBPqtNtD4cj0djgb1eIpUtzydThd1uJ9kkkibzKYL6aL5h9petbnL+bTce9n0lnbw3abvaLHJwbZtABETJci+8fdJkTO5xmJczZ5gVPPdfqg0OQFud3Ga59vpu162N1Lj7uaf2D6vt-flRPs25KO7R1WaYuDcyX6mj2v7KpmnxMlKQEKpWLZ7iWgHfrBp7BlBSHNnGbYDohwE-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-3FanTnp7u0xxegEYE0nqPWsUpTXfnhRPEXOsRgzojiATBxhOCrsO1Z4SgB4Xg+H4ARI1YZBuP33i+P4iwWMXEbkQYMAIOpbehOEkiu10QRx4nc8QAvBvL1nwRr+cPDaO5D3xDEQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the update section in your line mark:

"tooltip": {"signal": "datum"}

[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJgpgzgxgTgSwA4BcEHsB2IBcIAq6KAhgDYAEAwugK6YrmkKYTkwAWxcKAdCADQgA7gjAp2uAIwAmAAyzB7CAgDm7FLgAsAVgUgkxMGGYrc2wVFWYyUXAG1Q1gLYRcIZighwk6UsU8CIABuZDSueEwsXCAAvgC6gqQQKhCYYLY4DiAAZgikpG4wvuhwgSUIqRp4AEZEKOhOgcZwEDBoWG7s5QBeWCQFFgCeTrWk%20INI4SBQAI40XK7xgmD%20xPaOxC5uJNVJgSGkYRlZAB64eoNSOoIwbgCC%20bH8oGc4koKXb9oAzDf3jzFniBXtIPrhpAAOPS3PAPAqAl64X4gT6SXR-WEAoGvTRgnCQ6H-eHYsx4ySaQmY4mInAANjxAE5KSA4U8aRckcyAEI0UgAazYXEQXjZwKkeLkGJAPP5grgwtKCLF%20MZ3N5ApgQoqipJOGRn1patlmvl2tFOLx6JAMOl6rlCvNpJRWiNGq1IqVr3pzrervtZs950tzPwxEwfK85Cg7GQjreZJDYYjcCjMaQcdBPqtNtD4cj0djgb1eIpUtzydThd1uJ9kkkibzKYL6aL5h9petbnL%20bTce9n0lnbw3abvaLHJwbZtABETJci%208fdJkTO5xmJczZ5gVPPdfqg0OQFud3Ga59vpu162N1Lj7uaf2D6vt-flRPs25KO7R1WaYuDcyX6mj2v7KpmnxMlKQEKpWLZ7iWgHfrBp7BlBSHNnGbYDohwE-nBD4IWhuHIeOCZSgA8uIHq6v%20LoUVROo0uBnL0UojHKvuvqsdRNJnnRh6UWxmE3gJDF9iJNqCR6cRLNMmpJMcGxbHgZyCCgExTD4HiBHAYYpG4IhiBIywNMQzC4KAKwkNsxC7K4gi5BApBgG4ZwxEqzhTJcakaW4kQQNEgi6duUxKKo6iBJgCAwOEKBwGEgjdF46C4HFCXgKZ5k4JZqw2XZgSOc5bjzh5mxTEUpAlIE6mTG4JTGNYAwgMF%20mZCAADEtKSDAADs2Q9YE7VcncciUAAooNhowNkELaINMBgNIMCaNk80BRA3wMoN2Q7btIAJBlThmdg2XgLleA7HsDkVEVeC3O5B3ECc0DrCA5SVG4tQoPUjQWPJUxuUC730H5EDZBof1kF5sQHUUmC5KYp1QOpeynSoNCiBAAC0fjVE5Fk5H0ADKCBJVc12PHg7UwDTtMFX0ADqyhqFUUKyO5ghPQgGSgCoiAuTgaUQIIfOiNQlWlFT3zSzLsSAiAR1wHyikgDVUx87Q6YOXADQE9kxAxVUSlTFAXgVLYyznartlXSAGs0Eg1SfJ2HMK1wyuvWrfnMPZOQ640p1WWseCm8Ktjy6kRSQATlQiqdrygLAUOuQVN0C2K8ufIn-3FanTnp7u0xxegEYE0nqPWsUpTXfnhRPEXOsRgzojiATBxhOCrsO1Z4SgB4Xg%20H4ARI1YZBuP33i%20P4iwWMXEbkQYMAIOpbehOEkjy-UvhoOmI8qI1bhWTQjSu10QRx4nc8QAvBvL1nwRr%20cPDaO5D3xDEQA)